# Why is a pointer pointing to null evaluating to true?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have a custom data structure that is essentially a circular linked list. The end node points to the start node which points to the first node in the list. The list works perfectly as intended, I'm just not quite sure why the following code behaves the way it does:

```
List::~List()
{
    Node* p = end->next;
    end->next = NULL;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        Node* tmp = p;
        p = p->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

In the deconstructor, I set the current pointer (p) to `end->next` which, as I've said, points to start which points to the first data node. I then set `end->next` to null, which I assume means that start now points to nothing. But when it executes the next line `while (p != NULL)`, it evaluates to true. Why is that?

Comment: You set `end->next` to null but `p` isn't null. `p` is whatever `end->next` was before you set it to null. You'd need `p` to be a `Node**` if you want it to alias the value of `end->next`, `Node **p = &(end->next)`, then when you do `(*p) != NULL` you'd be following the `p` pointer back to the exact `end->next`, and if `end->next` had changed, `*p` would be able to see the updated value.

Comment: @ggorlen Ah okay I see. I was conflating pointer assignment with regular assignment. Thank you for the refresher!

Comment: Btw you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` in C++

Comment: Also, on nomenclature - the function you're working with is a *destructor*,   not a "deconstructor".

Answer (score 1):

> I then set end->next to null, which I assume means that start now points to nothing.

It does not. Or at least, I assume so; we cannot know since you haven't shown `start`. I assume that `start` is a distinct object and thus modifying member of `end` will not modify it. `start` still points to where it pointed to before the assignment. What the assignment changes is that `end->next` no longer points to where it used to point (which according to you was the start node). Similarly `p` still points to where `end->next` used to pointe before it was set to null.

Consider an analogous example which may be easier to understand due to no pointers:

```
int end_next = 42;

int p = end_next;
end_next = 0;
assert(p != 0);
```

The modification of `end_next` has no effect on the value `p`. It works the same way with pointers:

```
Node a_node;
Node* end_next = &a_node;

Node* p = end_next;
end_next = nullptr;
assert(p != nullptr);
```

And still same way when the pointer is a member variable (here, the example should be quite close to the original program):

```
Node a_node;
Node* end->next = &a_node;

Node* p = end->next;
end->next = nullptr;
assert(p != nullptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `end->next` to null but `p` isn't null. `p` is whatever `end->next` was before you set it to null.

You'd need `p` to be a `Node**` if you want it to alias the value of `end->next`, `Node **p = &end->next`, then when you do `*p != NULL` you'd be following the `p` pointer back to the exact `end->next`, and if `end->next` had changed, `*p` would be able to see the updated value.

Here's a simple example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    struct Node *next;
};

int main() {
    struct Node *end = new Node{new Node{nullptr}};
    struct Node *p = end->next; // pointer to a Node
    struct Node **pp = &end->next; // pointer to a pointer to a Node
    std::cout << end->next << std::endl; // addr(end->next)
    end->next = nullptr;
    std::cout << p << std::endl; // still addr(end->next)
    std::cout << *pp << std::endl; // 0
    delete p;
    delete end;
}
```

Here's a lines-and-boxes diagram:

After `p = end->next`:

```
.-------.
|  end  |  .------.
| [next]-->| Node |
`-------`  `------`
              ^
              |
           .------.
           |  p   |
           `------`
```

After `end->next = NULL`:

```
.-------------.
|     end     |
| [next=NULL] |
`-------------`

           .------.
           | Node |  
           `------`
              ^
              |
           .------.
           |  p   |
           `------`
```

You can see `p` is still not null just because `end->next` is.

With the double pointer `**pp`, after `p = end->next`, we have:

```
.-------.
|  end  |  .------.
| [next]-->| Node |
`---^---`  `------`
    |         ^
    |         |
.-------.  .------.
|  pp   |  |  p   |
`-------`  `------`
```

Now we have a pointer to the pointer `end->next`. After `end->next = NULL`, we have:

```
.-------------.
|     end     |  .------.
| [next=NULL] |  | Node |
`---^---------`  `------`
    |               ^
    |               |
.-------.        .------.
|  pp   |        |  p   |
`-------`        `------`
```

and `*pp` gives us `end->next`'s current value, NULL.